# how to upload image using ajax in php

Tags: php, ajax

```
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Image</label>
   <div class="controls">
    <input type="file" value="Browse" name="image" id="image" />
    <span style="color: #61625F; font-weight: bolder;"  class="sixth"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

ajax code below

```
$("#reg").click(function() {

        $.ajax({

            url: "process_service_person_register.php",
            type: "post",
                        data: "image": $("#image").val()}, 
                       });
```

how will i send the image to the "process file"

Comment: Use http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ It will be easy to upload images through this

Comment: not getting the exact code..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) object.

```
<script>
if ("FormData" in window)
{
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', $('#image')[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
               url: "process_service_person_register.php",
               data: fd,
               processData: false,
               contentType: false,
               type: 'POST',
               success: function(result) {
                   console.log(result);
               }
           });
}
else
{
    console.log('sorry, FormData object is not available.');
}
</script>
```

Without FormData, you will have to go old school like using the [hidden iframe](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/) method

Answer (score 0):

Here is my php page when i post through ajaxform

```
<?php
include('phpfunc.php');
$path = "images/news/";
$utime = time();
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "bmp","jpeg","gif");

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $name = strtolower($_FILES['uploadnews']['name']);
    if(strlen($name)){
        $extpos = strrpos($name, '.', -1);
$ext = substr($name,$extpos+1);
        if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)){
                $actual_image_name = $utime.".".$ext;
                $fpath = $path.$actual_image_name;
                $tmp = $_FILES['uploadnews']['tmp_name'];

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, '../'.$fpath)){
                    echo $fpath;
                }else{
                    echo "failed";
                }

        }else{
            echo "Invalid file format.."; 
        }
    }else{
        echo "Please select image..!";
    }
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to upload files using AJAX

BUT, you can imitate the behavior of AJAX by using hidden Iframe (other ways exists - but this is the most compatible way for old and new browsers)

for example:

This is your form:

```
<form target="upload_frame" action="upload_handler.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="control-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Image</label>
       <div class="controls">
        <input type="file" value="Browse" name="image" id="image" />
        <span style="color: #61625F; font-weight: bolder;"  class="sixth"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now you should have a hidden IFrame inside your page, and name it `upload_frame`

```
<iframe name="upload_frame" id="upload_frame" width="1" height="1" frameborder="no" ></iframe>
```

And in `upload_handler.php` or whatever file that suppose to handle your upload request you should output something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.onUploadCallback(callback_data);
</script>
```

This will call `onUploadCallback` function set on the original's page JavaScript.

The `callback_data` parameter better be JSON serialized so you can use it inside the function as a native JavaScript object.

For example:

function onUploadCallback(response){
    if(response.success)
         alert("File uploaded: "+response.file_path);
    } else {
         alert("Error while uploading the file: "+response.error_message);
    }
}

For making the all thing more generic - you should use "JSONP" like style and pass "callback" parameter to `upload_handler.php` with the name of the function you want to call. and then add it to the form as `hidden` field `<input type="hidden" name="callback" value="window.parent.onSuccessCallback" />`

After all that description - my real suggestion to you is - use an already made jQuery library for the task